# Difficult number sequence

Tags: number-sequence

33, 66, ?, 1212, ?, 1218

I just can't figure out how to complete this sequence. The last number throws off everything I try. Anyone have some ideas? I can perhaps see the missing numbers ending in 9 and 15, but that still might be the wrong pattern.

<sub>*Taken from: https://news.generiq.net/Trilogica/algebrica.html*</sub>

Comment: They make a few handful of these questions (32, to be exact), label it "IQ test" and is asking 35-40€ to grade the results? Good lord...

Comment: @votbear it's pretty simple, if you are dumb enough to pay, it means you have failed the test

Comment: [Related joke](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41859180#41859180)

Comment: If you got this from somewhere the most obvious answer is that the last number is a misprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is it.

> Goes up in multiples of $3$ and number of each colour increases each time. $$\color{red}{33},\color{blue}{66},\color{blue}{69},\color{green}{1212},\color{green}{1215},\color{green}{1218},\color{purple}{1521},\color{purple}{1524},\color{purple}{1527},\color{purple}{1530}$$.

or

> First digit(s) doubles each time. $$\color{red}{33},\color{blue}{66},\color{blue}{69},\color{green}{1212},\color{green}{1215},\color{green}{1218},\color{purple}{2424},\color{purple}{2427},\color{purple}{2430},\color{purple}{2433}$$

Comment: Would have upvoted if I didn't reach my daily limit :\ :D

Comment: @TheSimpliFire If you are correct isn't there a gap between the blue and the green colour?

Comment: maybe purple should start at 2424?

Comment: Looks plausible.

Comment: I think in the second sequence, there should be 1 more green term - 1221

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here. Another solution could be

> 129 and 615. Basically, we sum up the digits of previous number and append the consecutive multiple of 3 as follows:
>
>  3+3=6 (6),
>  6+6=12 (9),
>  1+2+9=12 (12),
>  1+2+1+2=6 (15),
>  6+1+5=12 (18)

That'd make the next one

> 1221

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! It's customary here to hide answers inside spoiler tags (type `>!` at the start of each line), to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves. That's a pretty clever solution, btw! Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site, and I hope you stick around!

Answer (score 0):

The complete sequence is:

> 33 66 39 1212 1515 1218

This because:

> 33=first number of sequence
> 66=add 3 to first digit and add 3 to second digit  
> 39=first digit of first sequence number and add 3 to second digit of second sequence number...

Answer (score 0):

> 33, 66, 69, 1212, 1215, 1218

Explanation (not sure though if it makes sense):

> 2nd digit: 3n

---

> 1st digit: 3n if log2 of n is an integer, and n-1 otherwise